# initialize javascript array value from c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, scriptmanager, registerclientscriptblock

I want to initialize JavaScript array value from c# in asp.net application. I have below code which i iterate through the loop,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),  "assignGroupParty" + i, string.Format("javascript:SetProspectGroupPartyID({0},{1});"currentIndex, currentQueue.PartyID), true);
```

here

> javascript:SetProspectGroupPartyID

is function which sets the array value at the currentIndex position.

```
 O/P:- [undefined, 37316]
```

it always assign at only one index and the other remains undefined. Can any one help me out on this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class for this:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsArray = string.Format("var jsArray = {0}", serializer.Serialize(numbers));
```

and then register it by using e.g. [`ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScriptBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx) method:

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
    this.GetType(), 
    "arrayDeclaration", 
    jsArray, 
    true
);
```